# How Deal with json option in sinfo command

Tags: json, slurm

When I am trying to run the following SLURM command

```
  sinfo --json -o="%P %.3a %.16F %N"
```

gives me the following error: `19342 Segmentation fault`

anybody face the same problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the `-o` option.

The [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html#OPT_json) says:

> **--json**
>
> Dump node information as JSON. All other formatting and filtering
> arguments will be ignored.

So it's no use anyway.